# Groupby year and apply function to another column - Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply

I have a multiindex, multicolumn dataframe:

```
  start  A          B             C          D
0 2019  35.156667   51.621111   18.858684    1  
1 2019  NaN         50.211905   18.991290   -1  
2 2019  42.836250   58.778235   18.788889    1  
3 2020  NaN         8.188000    17.805833    1      
4 2020  42.568000   55.907143   17.300000   -1  
5 2021  46.458333   42.293750   26.322500    1  
6 2021  43.675000   60.475000   29.520000    1
```

On a yearly basis (column 'start') I would like to fill NaN in column A with forward value if D>0 and with backward value if D<0:

```
  start  A          B             C          D
0 2019  35.156667   51.621111   18.858684    1  
1 2019  35.156667   50.211905   18.991290   -1  
2 2019  42.836250   58.778235   18.788889    1  
3 2020  42.568000   8.188000    17.805833    1      
4 2020  42.568000   55.907143   17.300000   -1  
5 2021  46.458333   42.293750   26.322500    1  
6 2021  43.675000   60.475000   29.520000    1
```

I was trying with:

```
df[['A','D']] = df.groupby('start').apply(lambda x: x['A'].fillna(method='ffill') if x['D']>0 else x['A'].fillna(method='bfill'))
```

But I get errors like:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any help? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with forward and back filling per groups and then set values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('start')['A'].agg(['ffill','bfill'])
print (df1)
       ffill      bfill
0  35.156667  35.156667
1  35.156667  42.836250
2  42.836250  42.836250
3        NaN  42.568000
4  42.568000  42.568000
5  46.458333  46.458333
6  43.675000  43.675000

print (df1.columns)
Index(['ffill', 'bfill'], dtype='object')

df['A'] = np.where(df['D'] < 0, df1['ffill'], df1['bfill'])
print (df)
   start          A          B          C  D
0   2019  35.156667  51.621111  18.858684  1
1   2019  35.156667  50.211905  18.991290 -1
2   2019  42.836250  58.778235  18.788889  1
3   2020  42.568000   8.188000  17.805833  1
4   2020  42.568000  55.907143  17.300000 -1
5   2021  46.458333  42.293750  26.322500  1
6   2021  43.675000  60.475000  29.520000  1
```

Also if only 2 values per groups and check `D` is not necessary (depends of data):

```
df['A'] =  df.groupby('start')['A'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)
   start          A          B          C  D
0   2019  35.156667  51.621111  18.858684  1
1   2019  35.156667  50.211905  18.991290 -1
2   2019  42.836250  58.778235  18.788889  1
3   2020  42.568000   8.188000  17.805833  1
4   2020  42.568000  55.907143  17.300000 -1
5   2021  46.458333  42.293750  26.322500  1
6   2021  43.675000  60.475000  29.520000  1
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, are you sure about this: df1['ffill'], df1['bfill']? I get key errors because it sees it as a column label. By the way, the dataframe is much larger with many rows each year.

Comment: @Luca91 - yes, it is in another new dataframe `df1` columns.

Comment: @Luca91 - Answer was edited, how working for you `print (df1)` ?

Comment: true! Still I am struggling because is a multi-column dataframe where A is a sub-column of an upper column that usually I call through df[('UpColumn', 'A')], so now it became a 3 level columns, do you know how to call that?

Comment: it works with df[('UpColumn', 'A', 'ffill')] thanks!